# Loading data after a JSF page has completed rendering

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces, lazy-loading

I'm using Richfaces 4 and Mojarra 2.0.4. So I'll be glad if the answer is specific to Richfaces 4 framework :)

I understand that the JSF components are processed at the server side. Some of my pages are really data centric. So when I load that page (eg: inside a richTab with switchType ajax), it takes a lot of time for my bean to execute the method marked with `@PostConstruct` to execute and fetch data. And hence the time period between user clicking on the tab's header and actual page rendering is quite large, a really bad user experience. I've implemented lazy loading for the dataTables in the page but that still doesn't optimize my page load time since `@PostConstruct` is still there.

Is there anyway I can load the page first and THEN fetch the data with ajax and update the page? This loading time is really annoying for the user.Any help appreciated :)

PS: I thought of using the `oncomplete` and `onbeforedomupdate` client side events of `rich:tab` and call ajax functions declared with `a4j:function`. But it seems that these events are fired *before* the page is actually switched.

Answer (score 1):

use `onload` event of `<body>` tag in html along with `<a4j:jsFunction>`

If you still feel your page is not rendering completely before the method called then use `setTimeout('a4jfunctionName',10)` javascript function in `onload` to complete the rendering first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, If we're to use onload event, I will have to check which bean's which method to call based on which tab is loaded.Right? But your answer just gave me an idea! I could use oncomplete on rich:tab along with setTimeout! Will try and get back. :)

Comment: @Nikhil - yeah thats true, or else you will have to load all the data at the same time, Good luck :)

Comment: Well just found out that the oncomplete method of the first tab doesn't get executed! if i switch to other tab and get back to the first, only then oncomplete of the first tab is executed. So I can't use this strategy for the first tab. :|

Comment: Finally could get it. Called the a4j:jsFunction in the $(document).ready of that particular page. Eg: If my first tab laods page tab1.xhtml then put the call loadTab1() in the $(document).ready defined in tab1.xhtml. Didnt have to use the delay either :)

Comment: @Nikhil- yes thats a better strategy if you have used `jQuery`, the same you could do with `onload` event.